# Convert image data

Tags: r, image, web-scraping

I tried to scrape a seafood price data from [this](http://www.zgsc123.com/show-92-174146-1.html)) website. The website appears to protect their data by storing the price data as image. I was able to extract the image location, into excel, but how can I use R command to convert the link to the number showed in the image?

I attached below a subset data for your reference:

- species : sp1
- date : 2017-07-02
- market : shanghai
- spec : weight≥100
- [price.link](http://www.zgsc123.com/api.php?op=creatimg&txt=Z04eZ1o%3D&fonttype=4&fontsize=10&font=&fontcolor=000000&transparent=1)

Comment: the functionality you are looking for is called Optical Character Recognition, or OCR. you should look into some libraries that try to implement this; it's not an exact science but with reasonably legible images you should be able to get something pretty accurate

Comment: Check out the `tesseract` package [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-new-tesseract-package-high-quality-ocr-in-r/)

Comment: The number seems to be encoded in the `txt` parameter of the URL, so if you can work out the encoding scheme you might be able to work out the number without having to do character recognition. But it might be using some cryptographic coding scheme that's impossible to reverse-engineer, but somehow I doubt it.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma, ocr('http://www.zgsc123.com/api.php?op=creatimg&txt=Z04eZ1o%3D&fonttype=4&fontsize=10&font=&fontcolor=000000&transparent=1') does not seem to work.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma, but if i add "/api.png" in the end of url copied above, it almost works; e.g.,., ocr('http://www.zgsc123.com/api.php?op=creatimg&txt=ZFYIZg%3D%3D&fonttype=4&fontsize=10&font=&fontcolor=000000&transparent=1/api.png) gives me "7.87\n\n", while the real value is 7.87. it seems OCR has problem to read decimal point.